# Hide Ajax Form After Submit

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm using this simple ajax form and it's working well: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form#comments

There is one little change that I need to do.

Is there a way, using this form, to hide it after message sent?

Until now I only try using toggle jQuery function in Submit button, but in this way the form desapear even if the mail wasn't sent.

I know I need to use a listener in my html, so the browser knows when hide the form, but I'm very begginer in Js, ajanx, json, etc...

Thank in advance and I'm SORRY about my english, i'm a code and language self learner  ;)

Comment: Can you provide your jQuery code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it in the `done` function of your ajax call :

```
.done(function(response) {
    // …
    // Clear the form.
    $('#name').val('');
    $('#email').val('');
    $('#message').val('');
    // Hide the form
    $('#ajax-contact').hide();
}
```

Comment: Mr. Dorian (Gray?) THANKYOU!!!
It works!!! Thank you man, one more little drop of knowlege!

Answer (score 0):

you can change your .done to

```
.done(function(response) {
    // Existing Code
    $('#ajax-contact').hide();
})
```

for more info refer http://api.jquery.com/hide/